# In Angular 4 the hook ngOnChanges is not firing on input

Tags: angular

I am pretty new to Angular2/4. I have created a basic component with an input field. The user input will be reflected in the other components that are bound to the user input. Now I want to setup a general listener to a value change.

I thought the OnChanges hook would be the perfect solution but ngOnChanges method was NEVER called. Am I doing something wrong?

Any hint appreciated...

```
import { Component, Input, SimpleChanges, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="name">
    <input [(ngModel)]="name">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() name: String = "abc"

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
    console.log('on change', changes)
  }    

}
```

Comment: ngOnChanges: Called when you will use @Input() to pass value from one to other component. Lifecyle hooks: https://www.thetechieshouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Angular-4-Lifecycle-Hooks-Overview.png

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`ngOnChanges` is not called every time a component property changes internally. It gets called when the databinding from the parent component pushes a new value into the child component. So if your parent component has

```
<child-comp [name]="parentValue"></child-comp>
```

When `parentValue` changes, the child component's `@Input() name` will change and that will trigger `ngOnChanges`

Take a [look at the docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence):

> #### ngOnChanges
>
> Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties...Called before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.

To be notified when your form inputs change, in the long run the best approach is to learn [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) because they make you create the `FormControl` objects in your component and expose a very simple observable that emits every time the form value changes.

If you wish to stick with template-driven forms, you can bind to the input's `keypress` or `keyup` event to fire whatever logic you want to run on change.

Comment: Source code showing where the ngOnChanges is actually called from https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/885f1af509eb7d9ee049349a2fe5565282fbfefb/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts - you can see it pretty tied into the directive code so that’s why it doesn’t work if you just set a value on a property manually

Answer (score 9):

why are you using ngOnChanges you can simply use

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="name" (input)="valuechange($event)">
```

or

```
<input [ngModel]="name" (keypress)="valuechange($event)">
```