# How detect changes in an input field as we type-in [Angular]

Tags: angular, typescript, onchange

I'm new to Angular. I'm trying few simple things. I've an Input field. I just want to detect changes. I want to call some code whenever I type into the field. I checked these articles:

1. [Documentaion: Angular - onChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)
2. [What is the difference between OnChanges and DoCheck in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629828/what-is-the-difference-between-onchanges-and-docheck-in-angular-2)
3. [Documentaion: Angular - Lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence)
4. [Stackoverflow: In Angular 4 the hook ngOnChanges is not firing on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768798/in-angular-4-the-hook-ngonchanges-is-not-firing-on-input)

Here's my code:

**my-component.component.html**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="text">
```

**my-component.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {

  text="hello world";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
  }

  // ngDoCheck() { // TRIED THIS ALSO
  //   console.log("Changes detected")
  // }
}
```

**Two important information:**

1. I tried `DoCheck` also, but this is not what I want. I want to see if **only input field's** value is changed or not. But `ngDoCheck` will be called after every slight change in the rest of the components also as it is using `zone.js` ( i read this somewhere).
2. I can't use `(keydown)` also as I want to implement validation code later. I want validation to happen as I type-in. But with keydown, i noticed that I've to trigger validation code with some key-press even after the entered value is valid, let's say a Date/Time.

Keeping above two points in mind, please correct me. Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmsqgr).

Comment: I'm trying all the answers one by one and running unit test cases also. I'll come back quickly. Thanks everyone. :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use `input()` : 
**Exemple :**

HTML :

```
<input [(ngModel)]="text" (input)="sendTheNewValue($event)">
```

TS:

```
let value:string;

sendTheNewValue(event){
this.value = event.target.value;
}
```

**in your exemple :** 
HTML :

```
<input [(ngModel)]="text" (input)="change($event)">
<div>the input value is : {{text}}</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, DoCheck, SimpleChanges, OnChanges, Input   } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges  {

  text="hello world";

  @Input() name: String = "abc"

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
    console.log("Changes detected");
  }

  change(event){
    this.text = event.target.value;
  }

  // ngDoCheck() {
  //   console.log("Changes detected");
  // }
}
```

Comment: This answer is also working. Let me show this to my tech lead. Please give me some time to accept.

Comment: Please explain this answer. I'm going to use this in production code. I may be cross questioned by the tech lead.

Comment: okey , `(input)` is an action that detect when a `char` is introduced to your input element , and by using the method `change($event)` you're sending event to get its value and use as you like, if you try to `console.log(event)` you'll see that it is an object that has too meany informations , but what is important to us is only it's `value`, thets what we get when we use  `event.target.value`

Answer (score 5):

Angular handles the change detection itself. You just need to hook into the logic when it happens. In most cases this will be preferable to using eventlisteners, which are proposed by most other answers in this thread.

Whenever your input is changed, angular accesses the variable the string is set in.

One way to do something when the variable changes would be to use a `get`ter and `set`ter.

```
  // create an internal variable (do not change manually)
  private _text;

  // getter function, called whenever the value is accessed
  get text(){
    console.log("the value was accessed")
    return this._text
  }

  // setter function, called whenever the value is set
  set text(text){
    this._text = text
    console.log("the value was set")
  }
```

I also edited your stackblitz to include an example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6qvlrh

Everything else remains the same. And you just have to use ngModel on text.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

These 2 changes are required to track the changes to input:

1. Update the component template to bind value and specify **(change)** event.
2. Update the component script to specify **onChange** method.

**Working solution:**

**1. my-component.component.html**

```
<input [(value)]="text" (change)="onChange($event)">
```

**2. my-component.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponentComponent {

  text="hello world";
  constructor() { 
    console.log("Text = " + this.text)
  }

  onChange(event: any) {
       this.text = event.target.value;
       console.log("New value = " + event.target.value)
  };
}
```

Comment: Hi Gopinath, this is not what I'm looking. In your solution it will detect the changes only and that too when enter is pressed. But in my case I want the detection to happen along with the typing. Here I tried yours: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ca2snj

Comment: Or maybe I missed out something. Please check that stackblitz.

Comment: Hi Tanzeel, I found that the 'onchange' is in fact getting triggered for every key typed in the text field. The event response is happening fine. The issue seems to be with the validation function (validate(sDate: string)) that is processing the changed value. This function needs to be updated to suit the requirement. No change is required elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think all the above answers are correct. I like the getter-setter method though it adds several lines of code. Just in case you'd like to test a third way of tracking changes y forked your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-myrrqo

It uses `@ViewChildren` and a subscription to the `valueChanges` observable:

```
export class MyComponentComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

  text="hello world";
  second="hi angular";

  @ViewChildren(NgModel) myInputRef: QueryList<NgModel>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myInputRef.forEach(ref =>
      ref.valueChanges.subscribe(val =>
        console.log(`${ref.name}'s value changed to ${val}`)
      )
    );
  }
}
```

In the template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="text" name="firstInput">
<input [(ngModel)]="second" name="secondInput">
```

I added a second input element to show that if you have more than one element with two-way binding you have to use `@ViewChildren`. If you only had one element you could use `@ViewChild(NgModel) myFirstInput: NgModel;` and the code would be even simpler.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'll show this solution also to my tech lead.

Answer (score 0):

in html

```
<input type="text" (input)="onChange($event.target.value)">
```

in component

```
onChange(value:string){
console.log(value) }
```